# Can't connect to Google cloud MySQL DB from Spring boot application running in K8

Tags: spring, docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have Google cloud MySQL instance.
This is how I'm trying to connect to the DB:

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
spring.datasource.driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${host}:3306/${database_name}
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.show_sql=false
```

When I run Spring-boot locally (Either as standalone application, or in Docker container), it works as expected and I'm able to connect to google instance. But once I deploy it as k8 pod to google k8 cluster, I get this error:

```
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509609037Zcom.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509624634ZThe last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509634325Z at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar!/:8.0.23]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509641816Z at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar!/:8.0.23]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509650943Z at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:833) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar!/:8.0.23]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509660187Z at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:453) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar!/:8.0.23]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509667583Z at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar!/:8.0.23]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509674049Z at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar!/:8.0.23]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509681366Z at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509689163Z at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509695511Z at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:155) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509711714Z at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:146) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509718794Z at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:205) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509725553Z at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:169) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509732733Z at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar!/:5.4.30.Final]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509740924Z at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar!/:5.4.30.Final]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509749641Z at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) [hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar!/:5.4.30.Final]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509756783Z at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) [hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar!/:5.4.30.Final]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509763753Z at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) [hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar!/:5.4.30.Final]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509770623Z at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) [hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar!/:5.4.30.Final]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509796702Z at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) [hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar!/:5.4.30.Final]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509802689Z at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar!/:5.4.30.Final]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509808731Z at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) [hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar!/:5.4.30.Final]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509815653Z at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) [hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar!/:5.4.30.Final]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509822479Z at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) [hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar!/:5.4.30.Final]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509829318Z at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar!/:5.4.30.Final]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509843010Z at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176) [hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar!/:5.4.30.Final]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509849856Z at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127) [hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar!/:5.4.30.Final]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509856595Z at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224) [hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar!/:5.4.30.Final]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509863586Z at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255) [hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar!/:5.4.30.Final]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509872075Z at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) [spring-orm-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509878468Z at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509884538Z at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:40
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509905668Z at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) [spring-orm-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509914159Z at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509920884Z at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) [spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509927455Z at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790) [spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509933694Z at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) [spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509939206Z at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) [spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509945426Z at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) [spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509959520Z at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509966550Z at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) [spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509973044Z at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509982819Z at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1109) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509989186Z at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[
2021-05-29T10:58:53.509995584Z at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.510004994Z at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.3.RELEASE]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.510011525Z at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.3.RELEASE]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.510018006Z at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.3.RELEASE]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.510023845Z at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.3.RELEASE]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.510033258Z at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.3.RELEASE]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.510039845Z at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.3.RELEASE]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.510046040Z at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.3.RELEASE]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.510052673Z at com.alekseytyan.logiweb.LogiwebService.main(LogiwebService.java:9) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.510060800Z at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.510067072Z at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.510073383Z at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.510079940Z at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
2021-05-29T10:58:53.510086547Z at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[logiweb-service.war:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.510092467Z at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:109) ~[logiweb-service.war:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.510098016Z at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[logiweb-service.war:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.510105920Z at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59) ~[logiweb-service.war:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.510113410ZCaused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.510126973ZThe last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.510154628Z at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.510162460Z at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.510179730Z at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.510187599Z at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
2021-05-29T10:58:53.510194600Z at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar!/:8.0.23]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.510200781Z at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar!/:8.0.23]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.510207172Z at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar!/:8.0.23]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.510214725Z at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar!/:8.0.23]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.510221716Z at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar!/:8.0.23]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.510228880Z at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar!/:8.0.23]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.510236037Z at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:953) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar!/:8.0.23]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.510242239Z at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:823) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar!/:8.0.23]
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.510248946Z ... 57 common frames omitted
Info
2021-05-29T10:58:53.510255264ZCaused by: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out) at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~
```

I was thinking it concerns stuff with external access and IPs, but it's just my assumpsions

Comment: You provided too few detail on your configuration, the error can come from several way! Do you use the public or private IP of Cloud SQL? Do you have firewall rule? Do you have a public IP on your node or a Cloud NAT? Do you use Cloud SQL proxy? If you use the Cloud SQL public IP which network did you authorize?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Hi, yes, I'm using public IP with 0.0.0.0/0 auth network

Comment: Do you have public IP on your Node ?

Comment: I have load balancer which provides me an external IP to my service

Comment: try doing telnet from the pod to cloud sql instance. but probably you have a networking issue.

Comment: @Alxa, it wasn't my question! Does your nodes (your vm, Compute Engine) have public IP? If not, did you have set up a Cloud NAT?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes, I have a node pool consisting of 3 nodes, each of which has static IP address. All these IPs are added to authorized connections in my instance configuration

Comment: (I know, I can be annoying sometime), but the static IP are public or private? My concern is: to initiate a connexion to a public IP address, you need to be publicly routable (and thus go to the internet with a public IP, the node public IP or the Cloud NAT IP).

Comment: A related question, is your GKE cluster is in VPC-native cluster?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I know know how hard it is sometime to delve into a problem. Regarding the question, the only thing I know is that I have static IPs on all instances of VM-pool and they are all external (Which I beleive is a synonym to public). I also don't think that my cluster is VPC-native as the only thing I did was entering a simple creating command in cli

Comment: And this is what I entered
`gcloud container clusters create CLUSTER_NAME \
    --release-channel CHANNEL \
    --zone COMPUTE_ZONE \
    --node-locations COMPUTE_ZONE,COMPUTE_ZONE1`

Comment: I also managed to connect to another DB (which is actually empty, though) withing the same SQL instance from another pod with the same connection configuration. That pod was running on the same VM-pool

Comment: It appears to be a problem with Spring configuration, after migration to Spring boot the problem dissapeared. I deleted custom WebMVC and DataSource config classes and let Spring boot do it for me. Now I can successfully connect to my Cloud SQL instance